# 3D rotations to connect balls and cylinders

Tags: python, math, 3d

I've been tasked with writing a python based plugin for a graph drawing program that generates an STL model of a graph.  A graph being an object made up of vertices and edges, where a vertex is represented by a 3D ball (a tessellated icosahedron), and an edge is represented with a cylinder that connects with two balls at either end.  The end result of the 3D model is that it will get dumped out to an STL file for 3D printing.  I'm able to generate the 3D models for the balls and cylinders without any issues, but I'm having some issues generating the overall model, and getting the balls and cylinders to connect properly.

My original idea was to create tessellated icosahedrons at the origin, then translate them out to the positions of the vertices.  This works fine.  I then, for each edge, I would create a cylinder at the origin, rotate it to the correct angle so that it points in the correct direction, then translate it to the midpoint between the two vertices so that the ends of the cylinders are embedded in the icosahedrons.  This is where things are going wrong.  I'm having some difficulties getting the rotations correct.  To calculate the rotations, I'm doing the following:

First, I find the angle between the two points as follows (where source and target are both vertices in the graph, belonging to the edge that I'm currently processing):

```
        deltaX = source.x - target.x
        deltaY = source.y - target.y
        deltaZ = source.z - target.z

        xyAngle = math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY) 
        xzAngle = math.atan2(deltaX, deltaZ) 
        yzAngle = math.atan2(deltaY, deltaZ)
```

The angles being calculated seem reasonable, and as far as I can tell, do actually represent the angle between the vertices.  For example, if I have a vertex at (1, 1, 0) and another vertex at (3, 3, 0), the angle edge connecting them does show up as a 45 degree angle between the two vertices. (That, or -135 degrees, depending which vertex is the source and which is the target).

Once I have the angles calculated, I create a cylinder and rotate it by the angles that have been calculated, like so, using some other classes that I've created:
                        c = cylinder()
                        c.createCylinder(edgeThickness, edgeLength)

```
        c.rotateX(-yzAngle)
        c.rotateY(xzAngle)
        c.rotateZ(-xyAngle)
        c.translate(edgePosition.x, edgePosition.y, edgePosition.z)
```

(Where edgePosition is the midpoint between the two vertices in the graph, edgeThickness is the radius of the cylinder being created, and edgeLength is the distance between the two vertices).

As mentioned, its the rotating of the cylinders that doesn't work as expected.  It seems to do the correct rotation on the x/y plane, but as soon as an edge has vertices that differ in all three components (x, y, and z), the rotation fails.  Here's an example of a graph that differs in the x, and y components, but not in the z component:

[image: The graph in the application]

And here's the resulting STL file, as seen in Makerware (which is used to send the 3D models to the 3D printer):

[image: Graph in Makerware]

(The extra cylinder looking bit in the bottom left is something I've currently left in for testing purposes - a cylinder that points in the direction of the z axis, located at the origin).

If I take that same graph and move the middle vertex out in the z axis, so now all the edges involve angles in all three axis, I get a result something like the following:

As show in the app:

[image]

The resulting STL file, as show in Makerware:

[image]

...and that same model as viewed from the side:

[image]

As you can see, the cylinders definitely aren't meeting up with the balls like I thought they would.  My question is this: Is my approach to doing this flawed, or is it some small but critical mistake that I'm making somewhere in my rotations?  I'm pretty sure it isn't a problem with the rotation functions themselves, as I've been able to independently verify that they work as expected.  I also tried creating a rotate function that takes in a yaw, pitch, and roll and does all three at once, and it seemed to generate the same result, like so:

```
c.rotateYawPitchRoll(xzAngle, -yzAngle, -xyAngle)
```

So... anyone have any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE: As joojaa pointed out, it was a combination of calculating the correct angles as well as the order that they were applied.  In order to get things working, I first calculate the rotation on the x axis, as follows:

```
zyAngle = math.atan2(deltaVector.z, deltaVector.y)
```

where deltaVector is the difference between the target and source vectors.  This rotation is not yet applied though!  The next step is to calculate the rotation on the y axis, as follows:

```
angle = vector.angleBetweenVectors(vector(target.x - source.x, target.y - source.y, target.z - source.z), vector(target.x - source.x, target.y - source.y, 0.0))
```

Once both rotations are calculated, they are then applied... in the reverse order!  First, the x, then the y:

```
c.rotateY(angle)
c.rotateX(-zyAngle) #... where c is a cylinder object
```

There still seems to be a few bugs, but this seems to at least work for a simple test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation happens in successive order, so the angles affect each other. It is not possible to use a Euler model to rotate them at once. This is why you can not just calculate the rotations based on the first static situation. Just imagine turning a cube so that it is standing on its corner upright. Yes  the first rotation is 45 but the second is not since the cube is already turned by that time (draw a each step of the sequence and see what happens). Space rotations aren't trivial.

So you need to rotate one angle then re calculate the second angle and so forth.  This is also why your first rotation works right. You only need 2 rotations unless your interested in making sure the rotation around the shaft has a certain direction.

I would suggest you use axis angles or matrices instead to do this. Mainly because in axis angles this is trivial the angle is the dot between the along tube start and end vectors and the axis is the cross between those 2. You can then convert those to Euler angles if you need. But probably you can just use the matrix directly. For ideas on how conversions and how the rotation could directly be calculated see: [transformations.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html) by Christoph Gohlke. Also see the accompanying c source.

**I think i need to expand this answer a bit**

There is a really easy way out for this question that sidesteps all your and many other persons problems. The answer is do not use Euler angle rotation. Ive used a lot of brainpower to try to explain Euler rotations to problems that are ultimately solved more easily without Euler rotations. To justify i will leave just one reason for this if you want more think up of some more answers.

The reason most to use Euler rotation sequences is that you probably don't understand Euler angles. There are in fact only a handful of situations where they are good. No self respecting programmer uses Euler rotations to solve this issue. What you do is you use vector math instead.

So you have the direction vector from the source to target which is usually calculated:

```
along = normalize(target-source)
```

this is simply one of your matrix rows (or column notation is up to model maker), the one that corresponds to your cylinders original direction (the rows are just x y z w), then you need another vector perpendicular to this one. Choose a arbitrary vector like up (or left if your along is pointing close to up). cross product this up vector by your along for the second row direction. and finally put your source as the last row with 1 in the last column. Done fully formed affine matrix describing the cylinders prition. Much easier to understand since you can draw the vectors.

There are shorter ways but this one is easy to understand.

Comment: Rotations happening in successive order makes sense, as well as doing just two rotations (such as one on the X axis and one on the Y axis).  One thing I'm still not clear on though.  Once I've done the rotation on the X axis, how do I then recalculate the angle necessary for the rotation on the Y axis? My attempts at doing such thus far have failed me. 

I much rather would have used matrices as well, but I'm working with a fairly narrow set of functions/classes, and trying to keep external dependencies to a minimum, hence doing it just by angles.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled on recalculating the angle.  Let's suppose I have an edge with vertices at (1, 1, 1) and (5, 5, 5).  I calculate the angle y/z angle as described above, and rotate on the x axis by that amount.  How does such a rotation affect the angle that I need to rotate around the Y axis?  I can't quite see how it would affect that angle, and why it would need to be recalculated, yet trying to do things that way results in incorrect looking results.

Comment: Usually 3d graphics programmers use matrix multiplication because its universal. However in your case imagine it this way if you rotate around the y axis (up in my case) than the angle for the next rotation is angle between original vector and original vector where the Z component is 0 now just make sure your original position matches this line of thought.

Comment: I'm still not quite following your last statement there, about making sure the original position matches the revised line of though.  I created a trivial sample with just two vertices (1,1,1) and (5,5,5). When I first calculate the angle for the rotation on the x axis, I get an angle of 45 degrees, which seems and looks correct.  When I then recalculate the angle for the y axis rotation, I get 35.264 degrees (or so). If I apply this rotation, it is close, but still doesn't quite line up, as shown by looking down the z axis: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144587/Graph6.png

Comment: I'm almost beginning to wonder if it isn't a problem somewhere else, such as the code that rotates the cylinder. 

If I look at the image, I can calculate the angle between the centers of the two spheres, and it comes out to be 45 degrees.  If I calculate the angle of the cylinder, it comes out closer to 30 degrees.

Comment: Your calculation is correct, but only assuming everything else is correct. Sound to me like your rotation order is not what you expect. However please note hat the order of rotation actually matters so make sure your object is working in where your first rotation is actually calculated first. And this is why anybody sane uses matrices. There is no guarantee that the program actually rotates stuff the way you say but rather it may set values of internal model items and then the rotation order matters. If you calculate in some order your world has to match your order

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply.  I was finally able to get it.  As you suspected, I was applying my rotations in the wrong order.  I'll update my original post with my solution, and mark yours as correct.  Again, many thanks!

Comment: I still am having one problem, and I'm sure it is to do with how I am calculating the second point.  Suppose that I have a point at (4.0, 0.0, 0.0).  If I use the above code to calculate "angle", the rotation comes out as 0 degrees.  This means when I do my rotation on the y axis, instead of pointing down the x axis, it continues to point down the z axis, and doesn't get rotated.  Any thoughts on how I should be properly calculating the location of the point after the first rotation?

Comment: @JoelB does you api have a method to set the matrix directly?

Comment: No.  I can certainly create such a method though.